# JQuery dynamic Script-Tag and the Execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

The goal is to load script-Tags per ajax, execute the scripts and show the content of the script-tag (a iframe with a video).

The scenario:
The scenario is a video page. If i click on "video-text" the id in the dom will be determined. After that an ajax-php-request will be executed with the determined id. This request will responese with a script tag. And this is the **problem**: How can i get the iframe?
Have anyone a tip for me?

ajax-call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/get-embed-by-id/"+$(this).find('.views-field-nid .field-content').html(),
    success: postToPageTwo,
    error : postToPageTwo,
    datataype: "html",
});
```

This call returns a script like this one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://exampleurl.de/video/7"></script>
```

The content of this script is for example:

```
(function(){ 
    document.write('<iframe id="video_11" class="mediacube_video" 
     src="http://exampleurl.de/video/11.html?" scrolling="no" 
     align="center" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" width="725" height="409">
     </iframe>');
})()
```

**EDIT**
the code to use with $.getScript:

```
$.getScript("http://exampleurl.de/video/5", scriptResponse);
```

and the code of scriptResponse:

```
function scriptResponse(data) {
  console.log("data:");
  console.log(data);
}
```

but the data is always undefined. or did i anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load and execute scripts for  you. no need to call an ajax to return an html to load another script (that's a lot of round trips) just to call a script.

```
$.getScript('http://exampleurl.de/video/7');
```

---

if the initial request really matters (maybe some parsing on the back-end to determine the link of the script), you can have the initial response return just the url of the script. then use that returned string for the `.getScript()`

```
$.get('initial_url',function(returned_url){
    $.getScript(returned_url);
});
```

but still, too many round trips.

Comment: try `console.log()` inside the function of the script you are fetching. if it does appear, then the script has executed.

Comment: ok i got a few other problems, but this was the correct answer of you. So i mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: From the `getScript` docs: "Success Callback: The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed."